# redirection of URL to new URL with 301 redirect not working in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web.xml

How can I prevent a user from accessing my app at myproject.appspot.com and force them to access it at myproject.com? I already have myproject.com working, but I don't want users to be able to access the myproject.appspot.com domain. I'm using Java Servlet/ServletFilter with 301 redirection.
Please guide me.

Comment: This should work if you send the proper 301 response back to user. Can we see the url?

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP referrer header and act correspondingly.

If it's on the right domain, serve normally, if not, redriect.